# как получить значение массива из документа в mongoDB?

Tags: golang

Документ из колекции

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b901b0d36a1f27d587f9d6b"), "name" : "Русское", "path" : "/russkoe",
"about" : "Здесь ты найдешь много интересного", "imgs" : [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ] }
```

Код

```
 type categories struct {
    Id    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Name  string        `bson:"name"`
    Path  string        `bson:"path"`
    About string        `bson:"about"`
    Imgs  imgs          `bson:,inline`
}

type imgs struct {
    one []string
}

// ShowAllCategories wdwd
func ShowAllCategories(s *mgo.Session, c *cli.Context) []categories {
    result := []categories{}
    categoriesCollection := s.DB("PronDB").C("categories")
    categoriesCollection.Find(nil).All(&result)
    return result
}
```

В переменную `result` попадает следующее:

```
{ObjectIdHex("5b911b3954a301eae93a6bd3") Русское /russkoe Здесь ты найдешь много интересного {[]}}
```

То есть массив пустой. Товарищи, как прихватить собой еще и массив? без него мне нельзя)

Comment: ``Imgs []string `bson:"imgs"``?

Comment: Можешь объяснить как это работает?)

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что в вашей структуре вам надо просто определить слайс строк:

```
type categories struct {
    Id    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Name  string        `bson:"name"`
    Path  string        `bson:"path"`
    About string        `bson:"about"`
    Imgs  []string      `bson:"imgs"`
}
```

Ваша отдельная структура не работает (помимо прочего), потому что пакеты, использующие отражение (например, `encoding/json`), не могут выставлять значения неэкспортированных полей. Кроме того, значение тэга всегда должно быть в двойных кавычках.